# Gulp js cssmin issue. Can't overwrite existing minified files

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, gulp, minify

Haven't found any help with my issue with search and google.

I'm having issues with Gulp and cssmin. Can't figure out what's causing an error. The idea is to keep original css files and minified version in the same folder, concatenation isn't needed. 
My gulp task code:

```
  gulp.task("min:css", function ()
{
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss], { base: "." })
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

And error I'm getting after running the task:

```
[13:30:47] Starting 'min:css'...
[13:30:49] 'min:css' errored after 1.59 s
[13:30:49] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '%file location%\bootstrap-theme.min.css' at Error (native)
```

UPD: After removing the bootstrap-theme.min.css, the error is caused by another one. Conclusion: the task can't overwrite the existing min.css files.

UPD:Managed to make it work with deleting all the .min.css files before build and running the task after the build. Not the best solution imo.

Is there any way to run the command without that, so all min.css files are deleted first?

Comment: Have you tried opening your console with Admin priviliges? or using sudo if your on a linux system? Just to see what happens.

Comment: I've tried that. The error message is directly from there.

Comment: Could you try passing in the property { showLog: true } to the cssmin ? Might provide us with more info. Is bootstrap-theme.min.css in an asset folder of yours, or is it trough bower or something? Where is it located. It seems to me like the file is "read-only", you could try changing the file permission if you are manually adding that file to an asset folder.

Comment: Ran the task with a log. It runs through all necessary .css files and still getting an error with the same bootstrap-theme.min.css, like it's not recognizing it's a .min.css file. 
Tried to exclude it separately in src options, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance your CSS files are in nested folders?

EDIT -

```
return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
  .pipe(cssmin())
  .pipe(plugins.rename(function (path) {
    path.basename += '.min';
    path.dirname += '';
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('{root folders name}'));
```

What this will do is rename the file with .min and add the file path to the name.
This will ensure the files go to the exact same place the originals are.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!
Even though all css files were under same folder.

Comment: Seems, it did it just ones. When tried to run again after deleted test files, got the same error. Sorry, but can't accept this option then yet. 

Upd: error triggered on the same file again.

Comment: doesn't help. 
Tried to remove the file that causes an error, it goes to the next file. 
Seems to me it can't overwrite the existing min.css files.